# introducing .htaccess file in PHP MVC Project

Tags: php, css, .htaccess

I've recently started working on mvc. My problem is the recognition of css files. 
When I added the line

```
RewriteRule ^([^\/]*)/([^\/]*)$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

to the .htaccess file, another css file does not know. but when change it to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

it works fine.

here is my .htaccess file detail

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|pdf|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|swf|pdf|txt|php)$
RewriteRule ^([^\/]*)/([^\/]*)$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

what can i do to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: it work fine, but i want use with 2 step in address direction. like it sample.com/page/12 and work with this pattern.